# Can't get sumifs to work with a nested function

Tags: excel

I have a set of data with one column having product IDs, and another column having the values.

I'm looking to take a sum of the column values, IF the IDs have a 7 or 9 as their 3rd character. I have a formula that I believe is very close, but not there yet:

```
=SUMIFS(E3:E821,A3:A821,MID(this,3,1)="7",A3:A821,MID(this,3,1)="9")
```

My problem is that I'm using the mid function in the criterias, but I don't know how to give it a variable to reference the current cell being evaluated. If I were programming in JavaScript, I'd use "this" to reference the current object, but that doesn't work in Excel. All of the examples I've been able to find have very simple criteria where you don't reference the cell itself in the comparison, which leaves me at a loss.

Comment: I understand what you are asking however I do not believe it is possible using simple excel formula. The reason for this is that the `sumifs` formula does not actually loop through the range specified but quickly checks whether or not a cell meets a specified criteria. It is therefore not able to manipulate the value of the cell(s) it is querying.

Comment: Also, your logic in your suggested code is flawed.
Currently you are checking to see if mid(this,3,1) is equal to 9 AND 7 simultaneously, which is not possible.
Take a look at nesting `OR()` too.

Comment: I did take a look at nesting OR initially, and using SUMIF (note, it's singular version), but I hit the same issue with the criteria, that it needed some kind of cell reference in the MID function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper column C:

```
=OR(MID(A2,3,1)="7",MID(A2,3,1)="9")
```

SumIfs function is then:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I'd be able to avoid that, but it doesn't look like I'll be able to, lol

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, without helper column, that I've not optimized.  It is an array function (so press CTRL SHIFT ENTER after typing formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(MID(A:A,3,1)="7",1,0),B:B)+SUMPRODUCT(IF(MID(A:A,3,1)="9",1,0),B:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even more simple:

`=SUMPRODUCT((MID(A:A,3,1)="7")+(MID(A:A,3,1)="9"),B:B)`

No CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and no helper column. Just one formula for what you want.

More information for this available [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/08/24/excel-sumproduct-function-formula-examples/).

[image]